# Iterating multiple variables over a list without double counting?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was working on part of a program in which I'm trying to input a list of numbers and return all groups of 3 numbers which sum to 0, without double or triple counting each number. Here's where I'm up to:

```
def threeSumZero2(array):
    sums = []
    apnd=[sorted([x,y,z]) for x in array for y in array for z in array if x+y+z==0]
    for sets in apnd:
        if sets not in sums:
            sums.append(sets)
    return sums
```

Is there any code I can put in the third line to make sure I don't return [0,0,0] as an answer.

This is my test list:

```
[-1,0,1,2,-1,4]
```

Thank you

*Edit: I should have clarified for repeated input values: the result expected for this test list is:

```
[[-1,-1,2],[-1,0,1]]
```

Comment: "all groups of three numbers" - does order matter?

Comment: The order of the three numbers matters which is why I used sorted(), it also helps for checking if sets not in sums

Comment: @game0ver, I would refrain from using .remove[0,0,0] because the input CAN contain three zeros, in which case [0,0,0] is valid

Comment: @game0ver it isnt a list of lists, but a valid input for [0,0,0] to be a valid output could be: [1,0,0,4,-2,0]. The output is a list of lists. Sorry, I should have clarified in my post.

Comment: @Newmsy No problem! I didn't know that - that's why I proposed the `remove` solution :)

Comment: @OlivierMelançon then you were right, I didn't notice that when I first read the description - the `itertools` way is a more elegant solution anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want combinations without replacement, this is something offered by `itertools`. Your `sums` can then be made a set to remove the duplicates with regard to ordering.

```
from itertools import combinations

def threeSumZero2(array):
    sums = set()
    for comb in combinations(array, 3):
        if sum(comb) == 0:
            sums.add(tuple(sorted(comb)))
    return sums

print(threeSumZero2([-1,0,1,2,-1,4]))
```

### Output

```
{(-1, -1, 2), (-1, 0, 1)}
```

This solution can also be written more concisely using a set-comprehension.

```
def threeSumZero2(nums):
    return {tuple(sorted(comb)) for comb in combinations(nums, 3) if sum(comb) == 0}
```

## More efficient algorithm

Although, the above algorithm requires traversing all combinations of three items, which makes it *O(n<sup>3</sup>)*.

A general strategy used for this kind of *n-sum* problem is to traverse the *n-1* combinations and hash their sums, allowing to efficiently test them against the numbers in the list.

The algorithm complexity drops by one order of magnitude, making it *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*

```
from itertools import combinations

def threeSumZero2(nums, r=3):
    two_sums = {}
    for (i_x, x), (i_y, y) in combinations(enumerate(nums), r - 1):
        two_sums.setdefault(x + y, []).append((i_x, i_y))

    sums = set()
    for i, n in enumerate(nums):
        if -n in two_sums:
            sums |= {tuple(sorted([nums[idx[0]], nums[idx[1]], n]))
                     for idx in two_sums[-n] if i not in idx}

    return sums

print(threeSumZero2([-1,0,1,2,-1,4]))
```

### Output

```
{(-1, -1, 2), (-1, 0, 1)}
```

Comment: I think you want `sums` to be a `set` rather than a `list` as well.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look more into itertools for future reference when iterating like this. Cheers!

Comment: @chepner I'm not sure of that, if a number appears twice in the input list, this might have some meaning we don't want to obsfucate

Comment: The OP's original code, at least, is filtering such dups. (`[-1, 2 -1]`, for example, appears multiple times as a combination.)

Comment: @chepner Oh I see what you mean. Let me update my answer

Comment: @Newmsy Please have a look at the updated answer. I added the optimal solution for these kind of problems.

Comment: @OlivierMelançon Thank you so much, this is EXACTLY what the question wanted as an output, and you have helped me loads in the understanding of it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `itertools` (see Oliver's answer), but you can also achieve the result with three nested for-loops:

```
def threeSumZero2(lst):
    groups = []
    for i in range(len(lst)-2):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)-1):
            for k in range(j + 1, len(lst)):
                if lst[i] + lst[j] + lst[k] == 0:
                    groups.append((lst[i], lst[j], lst[k]))
    return groups
```

and your test:

```
>>> threeSumZero2([-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, 4])
[(-1, 0, 1), (-1, 2, -1), (0, 1, -1)]
```

---

Oh and `list` != `array`!

Comment: I realised after posting how stupid my variable names were, will be more thorough next time

Comment: @Newmsy No problem!